# Xmlparsing using Ksoap

Tags: java, xml, java-me, ksoap

I am doing xmlparsing by using ksoap2. I had added ksoap2.jar file in my library.And done this coding

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport;


public class KsoapMidlet extends MIDlet {

Display display;
String strUserName= "Hello";
String strPassword = "World";
long ParentID;
String ChildIMEINumber;
String ChildName;
String serviceUrl = "http://www.semaphore.co.in/ChildTrackerService/ChildTrackerService.asmx";
String serviceNameSpace = "http://tempuri.org/";
String soapAction ="http://tempuri.org/AddChild";
String methodName = "AddChild";
Vector v=new Vector();



public void startApp() {
display = Display.getDisplay(this);
parsing();
// v.addElement("Hello");
// v.addElement("World");
// Constants d=new Constants();
// d.callSoap(methodName,v);
}

public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
notifyDestroyed();
}
public void parsing(){
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(serviceNameSpace,methodName);
request.addProperty("strUserName", strUserName);
request.addProperty("strPassword", strPassword);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.bodyOut = request;
envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
HttpTransport transport = new HttpTransport("http://www.semaphore.co.in/ChildTrackerService/ChildTrackerService.asmx");
transport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
transport.debug = true;
String result = null;

try {
transport.call("http://tempuri.org/" + methodName, envelope);
result = (envelope.getResponse()).toString();
System.out.println("***********************result********************************");
System.out.println("result=="+result);
System.out.println("Result :" + result.toString());
}
catch (org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException ex2) {
System.out.println("XmlPullParserException :" + ex2.toString());
System.out.println("Request \n" + transport.requestDump);
System.out.println("Response \n" + transport.responseDump);
} catch (SoapFault sf) {
System.out.println("SoapFault :" + sf.faultstring);
System.out.println("Request \n" + transport.requestDump);
System.out.println("Response \n" + transport.responseDump);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
System.out.println("IOException :" + ioe.toString());
System.out.println("Request \n" + transport.requestDump);
System.out.println("Response \n" + transport.responseDump);
}
}
}
```

But i am getting IO exception in line -----`transport.call("http://tempuri.org/" + methodName, envelope);`

The error mesage is:--

```
IOException :java.io.IOException: malformed header field <html>
```

Request
<`?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header /><v:Body><AddChild xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1"><strUserName i:type="d:string">Hello</strUserName><strPassword i:type="d:string">World</strPassword></AddChild></v:Body></v:Envelope>`

Response

```
null
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this same issue. The way i solved it was to change the profile settings on the phone. Go to the GPRS connection settings and change the protocol to HTTP (it was on WAP before).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the HTTP response is an HTTP 404 with an custom HTML error page. That is the only possibility I could imagine how to get an  in the web service answer.

May be your URL in transport.call(..) was wrong or the web-service on the server side was not active.

I would suggest to use a local http proxy like WebScarab (Java) or Fiddler (.Net) and redirect the calls to this local proxy. Then you will see what the server sends as response.

Comment: @ Robert Thanks for the reply i got the solution for it.it was because of proxy setting in my device.